# Update useState onclick not updating

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to update a useState object, my goal is to toggle the buttons and keep which button is on and which is off in the useState.

```
  const SalesChartCard = (data) => {
const [toggleButton, toggleButtons] = useState({
    'impressions': true,
    'purchasestart': true,
    'purchasecancel': true,
    'purchasecomplete': true
});
const buttonClick = (dimension) => {

    toggleButtons({
        dimension: !toggleButton.dimension
    });
};
return (
    <>
        <Button
            outline={toggleButton.impressions}
            onClick={e => buttonClick('impressions')}
            color="primary" className="mb-2">
            Impressions
        </Button>
        <Button
           outline={toggleButton.purchasestart}
            onClick={e => buttonClick('purchasestart')}
            color="secondary" className="mb-2">
            Purchase Start
        </Button>
        <Button
              outline={toggleButton.purchasecancel}
            onClick={e => buttonClick('purchasecancel')}
            color="danger" className="mb-2">
            Purchase Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button
           outline={toggleButton.purchasecomplete}
            onClick={e => buttonClick('purchasecomplete')}
            color="success" className="mb-2">
            Purchase Complete
        </Button>
    </>
    );
}; 
export default SalesChartCard;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state is an object. When you update an object you need to keep the previous value as well. So instead of creating a new object with your dimension key you have to use object spread to keep the previous state.

Besides that as your key is in a variable you need to use key inside [].

You can do something like this,

```
const SalesChartCard = (data) => {
const [toggleButton, toggleButtons] = useState({
    'impressions': true,
    'purchasestart': true,
    'purchasecancel': true,
    'purchasecomplete': true
});
const buttonClick = (dimension) => {

    toggleButtons({
        ...toggleButton,
        [dimension]: !toggleButton[dimension]
    });
};
return (
    <>
        <Button
            outline={toggleButton.impressions}
            onClick={e => buttonClick('impressions')}
            color="primary" className="mb-2">
            Impressions
        </Button>
        <Button
           outline={toggleButton.purchasestart}
            onClick={e => buttonClick('purchasestart')}
            color="secondary" className="mb-2">
            Purchase Start
        </Button>
        <Button
              outline={toggleButton.purchasecancel}
            onClick={e => buttonClick('purchasecancel')}
            color="danger" className="mb-2">
            Purchase Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button
           outline={toggleButton.purchasecomplete}
            onClick={e => buttonClick('purchasecomplete')}
            color="success" className="mb-2">
            Purchase Complete
        </Button>
    </>
);

}; 
export default SalesChartCard;
```

Answer (score 4):

The `useState` react hook doesn't shallow merge state updates, you need to manage this yourself.

For the given click handler: `onClick={e => buttonClick('impressions')}`

The `buttonClick` callback handler should merge existing state and use dynamic (*computed property name*) keys for updating the correct property. Use a functional state update to correctly compute the *next* state from the *previous* state. This ensures all previous state updates are correctly merged when updated.

```
const buttonClick = (dimension) => {
  toggleButtons(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    [dimension]: !prevState[dimension],
  }));
};
```